# Variable in many cypress files

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, request, cypress

I have a cypress test where the tests are in several files. Is it possible to assign a value to a variable in the first file (e.g. a token) and then use that variable in other files?

I tried:
Cypress.env("token", res.body.token) in before(() => {})

Example:

***file1.js***

```
before(() => {
  cy.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: "rest/v1/auth/...",
    headers: Cypress.env("headers"),
    body: {
      ...
    },
  }).then((res) => {
    Cypress.env("auth_token", res.body.token);
  });
});

describe("01_authentication", () => {
  it("Should login", () => {
    cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: "rest/v1/...",
      headers: Object.assign(Cypress.env("headers"), {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${Cypress.env("auth_token")}`, // it's OK
      }),
      body: {
        email: Cypress.env("email"),
        password: Cypress.env("password"),
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
    });
  });
});
```

***file2.js***

```
describe("02_submit", () => {
  it("Should submit", () => {
    cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: "rest/v1/submit/...",
      headers: Object.assign(Cypress.env("headers"), {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${Cypress.env("auth_token")}`, // here is undefined
      }),
      body: {
        email: Cypress.env("email"),
        password: Cypress.env("password"),
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This should work `Cypress.env("token", res.body.token)`, Have you tried checking whether you actually have a value for `res.body.token`? You can do `cy.log(res.body.token)`.

Comment: @AlapanDas Yes, the value is there because the tests in the first file pass. Without the token, they would be wrong. Only when I try to use "Cypress.env (" token ")" in the next file, there is no value in it.